# How to solve error 'The invoke url for function could not be found' in Logic Apps?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I added an action to my Logic App that was an Azure Function with blob trigger. When I tried to save, the next error popped:

`Failed to save logic app (Logic App name). The invoke url for function '(url)' could not be found. Please check that the function app runtime supports integrating with logic apps and retry the operation.`

Is it possible to integrate a blob trigger azure function in a Logic App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use a blob triggered azure function in a logic app. Only HTTP triggered azure functions are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Xavi Andreu

[Click here for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions)

Prerequisites
An Azure subscription. If you don't have an Azure subscription, sign up for a free Azure account.

An Azure function app, which is a container for Azure functions, along with your Azure function. If you don't have a function app, create your function app first. You can then create your function either outside your logic app in the Azure portal, or from inside your logic app in the Logic App Designer.

When working with logic apps, the same requirements apply to function apps and functions whether they are existing or new:

Your function app and logic app must use the same Azure subscription.

New function apps must use either the .NET or JavaScript as the runtime stack. When you add a new function to existing function apps, you can select either C# or JavaScript.

**Your function uses the HTTP trigger template**.